# Approximating probability measure by open and closed sets from a metric space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions, metric-spaces

> **Theorem 1.1.8** Every probability measure $P$ on $(S, \mathcal{S})$ is regular; that is, for every $\mathcal{S}$-set $A$ and every $\epsilon$ there exist a closed set $F$ and an open set $G$ such that $F \subset A \subset G$ and $P(G-F)<\epsilon$.
>
> Proof. Denote the metric on $S$ by $\rho(x, y)$ and the distance from $x$ to $A$ by $\rho(x, A)$ [M1]. $\S$ If $A$ is closed, we can take $F=A$ and $G=A^\delta=[x: \rho(x, A)<\delta]$ for some $\delta$, since the latter sets decrease to $A$ as $\delta \downarrow 0$. Hence we need only show that the class $\mathcal{G}$ of $\mathcal{S}$-sets with
>
> the asserted property is a $\sigma$-field. Given sets $A_n$ in $\mathcal{G}$, choose closed sets $F_n$ and open sets $G_n$ such that $F_n \subset A_n \subset G_n$ and $P\left(G_n-F_n\right)<$ $\epsilon / 2^{n+1}$. If $G=\bigcup_n G_n$, and if $F=\bigcup_{n \leq n_0} F_n$, with $n_0$ so chosen that $P\left(\bigcup_n F_n-F\right)<\epsilon / 2$, then $F \subset \bigcup_n A_n \subset G$ and $P(G-F)<\epsilon$. Thus $\mathcal{G}$ is closed under the formation of countable unions; since it is obviously closed under complementation, $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-field.

Why is it that we take $F = \bigcup_{n\leq n_0}F_n$? Certainly we want $F$ to be very large, but why not take $F=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$? Is there some reason that this would not allow that $P(G-F)<\epsilon$?

Comment: Infinite union of closed sets need not be closed.